# MySQL and PHP TimeZone

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In my `PHP.ini` file I set the TimeZone like so...

```
'America/New_York'
```

so when i ran a simple php Date() function

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

I get the Correct dateTime according to 'MY' system time as that's what i am comparing against and want to store in my MySQL db as well. (as reported from PHP).

Now the problem is, i exported a MySQL db to PDF format, just to see what it looked like, and the time was 1 hour back, ex.. it was (10:00 a.m.) here and the PDF footer said (9:00 a.m.)

So.. *i got to thinking*.. my PHP script will `INSERT` into the db the correct dateTime that i need.. But i have alot of dateTime comparing going on for accounts,

I know if i run any MySQL Queries in phpMyAdmin then i will get the **wrong** dateTime.

i have tried running in (phpMyAdmin SQL Query)

```
SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';
-and-
SET time_zone = '-05:00';
```

But when I run the query

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

I get back `SYSTEM` and `SYSTEM`.

(I should also mention i am on shared hosting)

If I use the MySQL `NOW()` function in my query, the time entered into the db will be calculated by MySQL, **according to it's own timezone**.

like this..

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (id, value, time_created) 
                        VALUES ('{$id}', '{$value}', NOW())");
```

I understand that I will have to do all of my INSERTING and comparing in PHP to keep the times right.. but with the above, it will insert the **wrong** time.

so this is my dilemma...

But will this affect anything that i am not foreseeing?  I just feel like somehow this will affect my times.

So how can I get around this or get MySQL on the SAME timezone? and make sure that ALL my date/times are right, not the 1 hour behind..

Comment: may be something like daylight saving, i just gueesing

Comment: Your code should change the session time zone just fine: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d41d8/304). How exactly do you run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two queries ran successively through PhpMyAdmin will be executed in two separate sessions (connections) therefore `SELECT @@session.time_zone` alone will always return "SYSTEM".

I doubt you can (and I hope you cannot) change the global time zone on a shared server, so always expect "SYSTEM" for `SELECT @@global.time_zone`. On the other hand you should be able to change your session's time zone.

Try running these two queries in one execution, it should show the new time zone :

```
SET time_zone = '-05:00'; SELECT @@session.time_zone; -- same session
```

`NOW()` returns time in the current session time zone, so time zone does matter. However I would rather store times in GMT time zone, but I suppose that's more a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you may do and what you may not do (on your shared hosting) you could choose to either use the following statement as the start of all your queries: `"set time_zone='-05:00';"`, for example: `"set time_zone='-05:00'; select foo from bar;"` or (maybe the most reliable option): only use timestamps in your tables and queries and create DateTime objects in PHP based on the timestamp you received.

Comment: Thanks, its probably easier to just make sure PHP takes care of setting all the date/times store them in $vars then just `INSERT` it as data, not DateTime or Timestamp

Comment: Beware, MySQL converts `TIMESTAMP` values to and from the session's time zone, unlike `DATETIME` values.